# Understanding Page allocation failure in my kernel module

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I implemented a kernel function and I am having a problem of kernel panic showing page allocation failure or oom-manager is getting invoked sometimes killing the process when I try to run my function very huge number of times(otherwise it’s fine). To debug this I started writing a dummy program which minimally simulates my actual program. My dummy program opens and closes a file(thats it !) . But I am running this function huge number of times when my module gets loaded as below

```
static int dummy(void)
{
 struct file *fd;
 mm_segment_t fs;
 fs = get_fs();
 set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
 fd = filp_open(“x/y/z/a.txt”,O_RDONLY,0);
 if(!fd || IS_ERR(fd)){
    return -1;
}
 //close file
 filp_close(fd,0);
 set_fs(fs); 
 return 0;
}
```

//init module function called when my kernel module gets loaded

```
static int dummy_init(void)
{
 int i, ret;
 for(i=0;i < 10000000;++i) {
    ret = dummy();
    if(ret == -1)
        return 0;
}
     return 0;
}
```

Now when i execute above code i have  “page allocation failure” or sometimes oom-manager is invoked and it kills the process. When I try to reduce the executions 
from 10^7 to 10^6 there was no problem. So here is the question .. for every iteration just opening a file and closing it using filp_close() before function terminates . So I don’t understand what is the problem. Moreover I see VFS:file-max limit warnings , hence I increased the limit to very large number. It also doesn’t make sense to me why file-max limit is reached though I am closing the file every time.

Below is the stack trace.

```
[  609.118491] vmtoolsd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[  609.120014] vmtoolsd cpuset=session-c2.scope mems_allowed=0
[  609.121145] CPU: 0 PID: 2194 Comm: vmtoolsd Tainted: GF          O 3.10.87 #2
[  609.122574] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 05/20/2014
[  609.124694]  0000000000000000 ffff88002f287978 ffffffff816b4c84 ffff88002f2879c0
[  609.126353]  ffffffff816b376a 0000000000000206 0000000000000001 ffff8800359e8000
[  609.127952]  0000000000000000 000000000007d336 0000000000000036 00000000000201da
[  609.129549] Call Trace:
[  609.130146]  [<ffffffff816b4c84>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
[  609.131162]  [<ffffffff816b376a>] dump_header.isra.9+0x7b/0x1a2
[  609.132323]  [<ffffffff8113884d>] oom_kill_process+0x1dd/0x330
[  609.133471]  [<ffffffff812a9105>] ? security_capable_noaudit+0x15/0x20
[  609.134751]  [<ffffffff81138fc4>] out_of_memory+0x464/0x4b0
[  609.135847]  [<ffffffff8113edf8>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x9d8/0xa20
[  609.137097]  [<ffffffff8117909e>] alloc_pages_current+0xae/0x160
[  609.138257]  [<ffffffff81135367>] __page_cache_alloc+0x97/0xb0
[  609.139436]  [<ffffffff81136dc4>] filemap_fault+0x174/0x3c0
[  609.140528]  [<ffffffff8115953c>] __do_fault+0x6c/0x620
[  609.141552]  [<ffffffff8115cd34>] handle_pte_fault+0x444/0x940
[  609.142696]  [<ffffffff8115e0fe>] handle_mm_fault+0x2fe/0x690
[  609.144058]  [<ffffffff811a8b00>] ? poll_schedule_timeout+0x70/0x70
[  609.145878]  [<ffffffff816be872>] __do_page_fault+0x1a2/0x580
[  609.147099]  [<ffffffff8108e955>] ? task_sched_runtime+0x55/0xa0
[  609.148574]  [<ffffffff81092185>] ? cputime_adjust+0x25/0x110
[  609.149878]  [<ffffffff81092841>] ? thread_group_cputime_adjusted+0x41/0x50
[  609.151458]  [<ffffffff81019ce9>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x20
[  609.152613]  [<ffffffff816bec7c>] do_page_fault+0x2c/0x50
[  609.153860]  [<ffffffff816baef8>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
[  609.155025] Mem-Info:
[  609.155532] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
[  609.156268] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[  609.157309] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
[  609.158063] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  54
[  609.159030] active_anon:0 inactive_anon:0 isolated_anon:0
[  609.159030]  active_file:19 inactive_file:81 isolated_file:0
[  609.159030]  unevictable:8 dirty:0 writeback:7 unstable:0
[  609.159030]  free:11595 slab_reclaimable:4672 slab_unreclaimable:216463
[  609.159030]  mapped:10 shmem:8 pagetables:7505 bounce:0
[  609.159030]  free_cma:0
[  609.165085] Node 0 DMA free:4108kB min:788kB low:984kB high:1180kB       active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB   unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15988kB managed:15904kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:72kB slab_unreclaimable:11668kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:12kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[  609.173628] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 832 832 832
[  609.174687] Node 0 DMA32 free:42272kB min:42340kB low:52924kB high:63508kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:76kB inactive_file:324kB unevictable:32kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:1032064kB managed:852376kB mlocked:32kB dirty:0kB writeback:28kB mapped:40kB shmem:32kB slab_reclaimable:18616kB slab_unreclaimable:854184kB kernel_stack:6048kB pagetables:30008kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:120 all_unreclaimable? yes
[  609.182737] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[  609.183616] Node 0 DMA: 7*4kB (UM) 6*8kB (U) 12*16kB (UM) 6*32kB (UM) 9*64kB (M) 6*128kB (UM) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB (R) 0*4096kB = 4108kB
[  609.186932] Node 0 DMA32: 1988*4kB (UEM) 3018*8kB (UEM) 379*16kB (M) 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB (R) = 42256kB
[  609.190003] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[  609.191646] 128 total pagecache pages
[  609.192376] 5 pages in swap cache
[  609.193043] Swap cache stats: add 125434, delete 125429, find 2279/2765
[  609.194314] Free swap  = 565836kB
[  609.194965] Total swap = 1046524kB
[  609.197207] 262143 pages RAM
[  609.197816] 11016 pages reserved
[  609.198461] 263966 pages shared
[  609.199090] 237462 pages non-shared
```

Comment: As I can see from memory is being allocated too aggressively, so memory gets fragmented with time , memory  used for files not freed immediately to buddy system but it is cached locally as file cache and ksawpd (kernel thread) takes some time to free memory of file cache to buddy system as system hit low memory situations , As from stack trace while allocating memory system is going in out of memory cases. so this is your story I guess.